# How to hold session with ClamAV daemon?

Tags: linux, clamav

I'm trying to connect to ClamAV daemon **clamd** on localhost 3310 port via **telnet** comand in terminal:`telnet 127.0.0.1 3310`

```
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
nIDSESSION [pressed ENTER button on keyboard]
nPING      [pressed ENTER]
```

But it gives error:

```
1: Only nCMDS\n and zCMDS\0 are accepted inside IDSESSION. ERROR
1: Error processing command. ERROR
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Entered zPING\0 [pressed ENTER] or nPING\n useless, prompts that error again.

Can you suggest anything?

Comment: Aren't you looking for [`clamdscan`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/clamdscan)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A fast look at `clamd` [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/clamd) suggests that `SCAN`, `INSTREAM`, `FILDES`, `VERSION`, `STATS` are maybe the only commands supported inside an `IDSESSION`.

Hence, you may need to move you `PING` command before starting a session.

Try this:

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 3310
nPING
nIDSESSION
nSCAN /foo/bar
nSCAN /foo/bar2
nEND
```

Note: Commands starting with `z` are for machines. As an interactive human you need to use commands starting with `n`. Do not type `\n` but hit `return` key instead.

Comment: What is `return` key, is it `ENTER` button on keyboard?

Comment: Yes it is.  `\n` is a new line.

Comment: After entering a session with `nIDSESSION`, the connection is closed due to inactivity after 3 minutes (`COMMAND READ TIMED OUT`). `nPING` inside an established session is supposed to keep it open until a useful scan task is available to be sent to Clamd. At least that's what I understand from the docs: `The client can use the PING command to keep the connection alive.` What's the point in sending the `nPING` before the session?

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely call nPING after nIDSESSION or you will be disconnected.

I resolved this issue by using nc instead:

`nc localhost 3310`

`nIDSESSION` 
`nPING` 
`1: PONG` 
`nPING` 
`2: PONG` 
`nEND`